# Different color based on what dropdown list value is

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have here the annual leave tool made by Daypilot, what I did extra is I added the Type of Leave ( vacation, medical and so on ) everything worked perfect, but what I want now is to have different color for each LeaveType I have.

I created a new table for this LeaveType, I was thinking to use an if where if the value from the database is selected set the backgroundcolor to something, but I'm not sure how I could do this.

Default.aspx.cs:

```
Protected void DayPilotScheduler1_BeforeEventRender(object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.Scheduler.BeforeEventRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = e.End - e.Start;
        e.Html = String.Format("{0} days", duration.TotalDays);
        e.EventMoveVerticalEnabled = false;
        if (-------in this if I should maybe say that if a specific value from table "Leave" is selected in the dropdown list-----------)
        {
            e.BackgroundColor = "#00ff74";
        }
        else
        {
            e.BackgroundColor = "#00ac74";
        }

    }
```

I also have here this New.aspx.cs where I have this dropdownlists:

```
public partial class New : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBoxStart.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["start"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
            TextBoxEnd.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["end"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");

            DropDownList1.DataSource = dbGetResources();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "PersonName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "PersonId";
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["r"];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();


            DropDownList2.DataSource = dbGetResources1();
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Reasonforleave";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["0"];
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how can I use that `DropDownList2`, to check what value is selected and based on that to have specific color. Or if you know a better way to do this? I expect the color of the box to be different based on the type of leave.
Here is a screenshot with the aspect of app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONIJl.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: What is the Control that creates the table as seen in the screenshot? Controls like a GridView, Repeater etc have a DataBound event that you can probably use to change the color.